# Is it possible to pass undefined variable as yield argument in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I was wondering if something like this would be possible say we have

```
def call_something
    yield a
end
```

where a is an undefined variable? Is this kind of thing possible and if so can you provide an example of how it can be useful?

I know you can pass arguments to yield but so far I know you can only pass actual arguments that have actual values.

To clarify, I meant something like this:

```
class A
  def initialize
    print "Enter a value: "
    @a = gets.chomp
  end

  def m
    yield @a
  end
end

a = A.new
a.m do |x|
  puts "You entered #{x}"
end
```

Where you could supply something and then pass a block using that 'something' as an argument.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Just edited my question to clarify what I meant.

Comment: That code should work. Instance variables evaluate to nil when undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you could, I'm not sure it would make sense, as to *use* that value in the passed block you would have to assign it to an identifier:

```
call_something do |arg|
  # you want `arg` to be the "unidentified" value
end
```

At that point, it's not the same "unidentified variable" you were talking about before, and the only way you can really represent it is as `nil`. So you may as well just pass `nil` in the first place